# WooCommerce send E-Mail copy to E-Mail Address from custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I want to send a copy of the completed order, failed order and canceled order to a specific E-Mail address. This E-Mail address is stored in a custom field I created with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

The field name is "e-mail_adresse". As I am using a multisite network I cant enter the E-Mail Address manually and have to pull it from this field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_cc_email_headers', 10, 3 );

function custom_cc_email_headers( $header, $email_id, $order ) {

    //Only for "Completed,cancelled, failed Order" email notification
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' !== $email_id || 'cancelled_order' !== $email_id || 'failed_order' !== $email_id )
        return $header;

    //Get the CC email
    $custom_user_email = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'e-mail_adresse', true );

    if ( !empty( $custom_email ) )
        return $header; // Exit (if empty value)


//Get customer full name
    $user_name   = $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ';
    $user_name   .= $order->get_billing_last_name();

    $formatted_email = utf8_decode( $user_name . ' <' . $custom_user_email . '>' );

    //Add Cc to headers
    $header .= 'Cc: ' . $formatted_email . '\r\n';

    return $header;
}
```

Try this code

Comment: thanks for your code. I tested it and did not get any E-Mail to the given address.

Comment: $custom_user_email = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'e-mail_adresse', true );
Is it returning the correct email id?

Comment: how can i test this? Sorry i am not very good in that kind of things :(

Comment: Just for explanation: the custom field is no custom user field. It is a custom field in afc options page.

Comment: Then need to change the logic of the above commented line

Comment: I tried this but this did not work <code>//Get the CC email
    $custom_user_email = get_field( "e-mail_adresse", true );</code>